# Why vector access operators are not specified as noexcept?

Tags: c++, exception, c++11, stl, noexcept

Why `std::vector`'s `operator[]`, `front` and `back` member functions are not specified as `noexcept`?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The standard's policy on `noexcept` is to only mark functions that *cannot* or *must not* fail, but not those that simply are specified not to throw exceptions. In other words, all functions that have a limited domain (pass the wrong arguments and you get undefined behavior) are not `noexcept`, even when they are not specified to throw.

Functions that get marked are things like `swap` (must not fail, because exception safety often relies on that) and `numeric_limits::min` (cannot fail, returns a constant of a primitive type).

The reason is that implementors might want to provide special debug versions of their libraries that throw on various undefined behavior situations, so that test frameworks can easily detect the error. For example, if you use an out-of-bound index with `vector::operator[]`, or call `front` or `back` on an empty vector. Some implementations want to throw an exception there (which they are allowed to: since it's undefined behavior, they can do anything), but a standard-mandated `noexcept` on those functions makes this impossible.

Comment: Out of bounds is undefined behaviour, and in case of undefined behaviour anything can happen. Undefined behaviour is not restricted by noexcept. Though when an exception happens, being noexcept will surely terminate, which is probably not desired in testing frameworks.

Comment: @PlasmaHH In theory, you are right. Once undefined behavior is invoked, a function that is `noexcept` could actually unwind. However, the practical considerations of code generation and the fact that such debug modes turn undefined behavior into defined behavior (throw an exception) make this a non-viable approach to writing a C++ implementation. If a function is `noexcept`, the caller might well be missing unwind tables, so trying to unwind would crash or send execution into never-never land, and that kind of defeats the point of throwing an exception.

Comment: So by that logic, noexcept function can be given just any argument?

Comment: Presumably, @curiousguy, provided the argument is valid for the type.  If a function is `noexcept` and takes a `T`, then that function is stating that it cannot/must not fail for any value of `T`, after all.  Building on the examples given, a `vector::operator[](i) noexcept` might perform bounds checking like `vector::at()`, and return a sentinel value for any `i >= size()` instead of throwing an exception.

Answer (score 19):

As a complimentary to @SebastianRedl 's answer: why you will need `noexcept`?

### noexcept and std::vector

As you might have known, a `vector` has its capacity. If it's full when `push_back`, it will allocate a bigger memory, copy(or move since C++11) all existing elements to the new trunk, and then add the new element to the back.

[image: Use copy constructor to expand a vector]

But what if an exception is thrown out while allocating memory, or copying the element to the new trunk?

- If exception is thrown during allocating memory, the vector is in its original state. It's fine just re-throw the exception and let user handle it.
- If exception is thrown during copy existing elements, all copied elements will be destroyed by calling destructor, allocated trunk will be freed, and exception thrown out to be handle by user code. (1)
  After destroy everything, the vector is back to the original state. Now it's safe to throw exception to let user handle it, without leaking any resource.

#### noexcept and move

Come to the era of C++ 11, we have a powerful weapon called `move`. It allows us to steal resources from unused objects. std::vector will use `move` when it needs to increase(or decrease) the capacity, *as long as* the `move` operation is **noexcept**.

Suppose an exception throws during the move, the previous trunk is not the same as before `move` happens: resources are stolen, leaving the vector in an *broken* state. User cannot handle the exception because everything is in an nondeterministic state.

[image: Use move constructor to expand a vector]

That's why `std::vector` relies on `move constructor` to be **noexcept**.

This is a demostration how client code would rely on `noexcept` as an interface specification. If later the `noexcept` requirement is not met, any code previously depends on it will be broken.

---

### Why not simply mark all function as `noexcept`?

Short answer: exception safe code is hard to write.

Long answer: `noexcept` set a strict limit to developer who implement the interface. If you want to remove the `noexcept` from an interface, the client code might be broken like the vector example given above; but if you want to make an interface `noexcept`, you are free to do it at any time.

Thus, only when necessary, mark an interface as `noexcept`.

---

In the [Going Native 2013](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/An-Effective-Cpp11-14-Sampler), Scott Meyers talked about above situation that without `noexcept`, the sanity of a program will fail.

I also wrote a blog about it: https://xinhuang.github.io/posts/2013-12-31-when-to-use-noexcept-and-when-to-not.html

Answer (score 7):

In short, there are functions specified with or without `noexcept`. It is intended, because they are different. The principle is: a function with undefined behavior specified (e.g. due to improper arguments) should not be with `noexcept`.

[This paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3279.pdf) explicitly specified these members being without `noexcept`. Some members of `vector` were used as examples:

> Examples of functions having wide contracts would be `vector<T>::begin()` and `vector<T>::at(size_type)`. Examples of functions not having a wide contract would be `vector<T>::front()` and `vector<T>::operator[](size_type)`.

See [this paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3248.pdf) for initial motivation and detailed discussion. The most obvious realistic problem here is testability.

Comment: Definition of `wide contract` from the same paper: A wide contract for a function or operation does not specify any undefined behavior.  Such a contract has no preconditions: A function with a wide contract places no additional runtime constraints on its arguments, on any object state, nor on any external global state.