# Why are std::array::front and std::array::back not noexcept?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, c++14, noexcept

I'm new to the use of the `noexcept` specifier and I do not understand why `std::array::front` and `std::array::back` are not declared `noexcept` (whereas `std::array::begin` and `std::array::end` are).

What is the reason of that?

Comment: Good question. They would have to be conditionally noexcept on the array size being non-zero. But vendors can strengthen noexceptness as QoI...

Comment: @KerrekSB Not even conditionally as `std::array<T, 0>` could be specialized to not have those `noexcept` contrary to `std::array<T, N>`. Unfortunately the standard does not provide that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

> There is a special case for a zero-length array `(N == 0)`. In that case, `array.begin() == array.end()`, which is some unique value. The effect of calling `front()` or `back()` on a zero-sized array is undefined.

So since we can have a 0 sized array `front()` and `back()` could cause an exception

To quote [Sebastian Redl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8922/sebastian-redl) on [why the standard doesn't mandate `operator[]`, `front` and `back` be marked `noexcept`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20517333/4342498)

> The standard's policy on `noexcept` is to only mark functions that cannot or must not fail, but not those that simply are specified not to throw exceptions. In other words, all functions that have a limited domain (pass the wrong arguments and you get undefined behavior) are not `noexcept`, even when they are not specified to throw.

Comment: But that's a static condition, so the `noexcept` could be conditional (just like `vector`'s default constructor).

Comment: @KerrekSB [Maybe relevant?](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:hEGrzM8rlE0J:gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2013-09/msg01397.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=pl)

Comment: @KerrekSB Added to the answer.  let me know if that is enough.

Comment: @NathanOliver That doesn’t really answer Kerrek’s concern: on a nonzero `array`, `front` and `back` cannot fail. This is known at compile time (since the array size is known at compile time), hence these functions could be `noexcept`, even accounting for the quote you added.

Comment: None of your answer is relevant. This isn't about narrow contracts. `std::array` is not a dynamic container.