# Why std::map find() is not declared as noexcept?

Tags: c++, dictionary, noexcept, exception-specification

C++14 standard defines the find() member functions of `std::map` as follows:

```
iterator find(const key_type& x);
const_iterator find(const key_type& x) const;
```

Why are these functions not defined as `noexcept`? What could possibly go wrong inside, that would require to throw an exception or produce undefined behavior (other than not finding an element in which case the function returns an `end` iterator and no exception throwing would be required anyway)?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20517259/why-vector-access-operators-are-not-specified-as-noexcept

Comment: I don't think the `Compare` function of a map have to be noexept, so I don't think `find()` could be noexept since it compare keys

Comment: @88877 Of course, `Compare` can throw indeed: `23.2.4.1.1` of C++14 states `erase(k) does not throw an exception unless that exception is thrown by the container’s Compare object (if any).` Please make your comment an answer.

Comment: Well, `noexcept(Compare)` is still an option.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`find()` are based on the `Compare()` method of the map, that could throw an exception (imagine the case of a complex key that could be incorrect). So, we can not be sure that `find()` won't raise an exception.