# C++ exception, undefined behavior and noexcept

Tags: c++, exception, undefined-behavior, noexcept

About this function

```
int test(int a,int b)
{
    return a/b;
}
```

If I call `test(2,1)`, nothing happens.
But if I call `test(2,0)`, it causes undefined behavior.
As a result, should I define it as `noexcept`?
BTW, why is `std::vector::operator[]` not `noexcept`?

Comment: The second question is asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20517259/why-vector-access-operators-are-not-specified-as-noexcept

Comment: @JamesRoot Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I define it as `noexcept`?

You certainly can, if you want. It is true in that the function won't throw an exception. It still can fail from division by zero, however.

It depends on what you think `noexcept` should mean. The standard library seems to treat it as a keyword meaning the function can't possibly fail, not just that it doesn't throw. If you follow their convention, you shouldn't make it `noexcept`. However, if you want `noexcept` to mean only that it doesn't throw, then you should.

Either way, you should always use the same convention. Outside of constructors and assignment operators, there isn't a large benefit either way.