# Why is noexcept not used more in the standard library?

Tags: c++, c++11

Since [`noexcept`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec) was introduced and addressed many of the problems with [`throw()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec), there is now a reason for specifying whether a function does not throw an exception. While it is not a compile time restriction, it will enable some potential optimizations by the compiler, and if nothing else, a signalling, and documentation, value for the user of the function.

In light of this I was actually a bit surprised, when I browsed through the standard functions such as: [`std::time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time), [`std::timespec_get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/timespec_get), and [`std::memcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcmp), and saw that none of them used the `noexcept` specifier. It is not like there are no functions at all using it, in the standard library, for instance the [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) function uses it, and others as well. But a large portion of functions, do not use it.

I guess it makes sense for functions that have undefined behaviour in certain situations, such as [`std::strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen), since this will allow implementers more freedom.

But for functions where there are no specified situations which can lead to undefined behaviour, and which obviously do not throw exceptions, why would these functions not be declared using the `noexcept` specifier?

It cannot only be due to keeping similarity with the old C functions, since for instance `std::timespec_get` is a new function in C++11, so it must be for some other reason.

The compiler might very well be smart enough to detect that the functions will not throw exceptions, and as such be able to do the same optimizations. But in my opinion one of the best arguments for `noexcept` is the documentation value, that comes from it, which will be lacking, when it is missing.

Which leads me to my final hypothesis, that the missing `noexcept` specifiers in the standard library are really oversights, much like it was the case with the [missing `std::make_unique`](https://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/). But unlike the missing `std::make_unique` which was corrected (implemented) in C++14, the functions above, have still not (as of C++17) been made `noexcept`.

Does anyone know the reasoning behind the missing `noexcept` specifiers, or am I right in thinking that this is an oversight?

Comment: You'd have to ask the comity. Keep in mind that once you declare a function `noexcept`, removing it would be a breaking change. You can always add it later while maintaining backwards compatibility.

Comment: See the first paragraph [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20517333/4342498).  Might be what you are looking for

Comment: @NathanOliver that is actually an interesting post. However not only functions that have specified undefined behaviour lack the `noexcept` specifier, but also function that "cannot" or "must not" fail, can lack them. At least it appears such from my short investigation.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The point about potentially breaking backwards compatibility if introducing exceptions for the function, is actually really interesting, and not something I had thought about. But is it really likely with the `std::memcmp` function? I guess it could be.

Comment: `timespec_get` is a C11 function that C++17 imported.

Comment: @TommyAndersen Can you give me an example of a function that cannot or must not fail that is not marked with `noexcept`?  Also [here](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Re-noexcept) is a link to what the CPP core guidelines have to say about `noexcept`.

Comment: @T.C. you mean C11 function? but yes you are actually correct, it slipped my attention.

Comment: Right, also it's C++17. I got confused because you said it's in C++11 - and C++11 doesn't import anything from C11.

Comment: @NathanOliver I guess the [`std::iswspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/iswspace) could be such an example?

Comment: @T.C. good point.

Comment: @TommyAndersen That one has UB if you pass it something neither representable as a `wchar_t` nor equal to `WEOF`.

Comment: If you think there are functions that really ought to be `noexcept`, but are not currently, and there would be no downsides to making them so (and I'm *not* saying there are no such functions), why don't you then write up a proposal for the standards committee to consider that includes your rationale(s) and submit it?  The standard doesn't evolve by magic you know; it requires knowlegable and engaged members of the public to participate in order to make good progress :)

Comment: There's also the reality that C++ library implementations often do not have control over the C library implementation, so adding C++-specific polishes to stuff from the C library is difficult (especially now that noexcept is part of the function type).

Comment: I think that you got the primary reason. Many of the functions are C and thereby implicitly `noexcept`. To me it sounds a little crazy starting adding C++ modifiers

Answer (score 1):

Rephrasing what you wrote above,

how can you guarantee **noexcept** when things are passed by pointers?

When you write your custom classes/functions, you can mark things noexcept without no guarantee of throwing no exception. But you probably do not want to do it when you are not absolutely sure that your function will not throw in any case.